# Issue IN VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a new vs code user. When I installed vs code and runned a C program "Hello World" and other programs but I face one issue undefined reference to winMain@16 I also have MinGW compiler. I searched for this issue in the whole internet but I didn't find anything regarding this visual studio code issue. If you have a solution to this please reply.

~~ Joydeep

Comment: Have you defined a main method in your program?

Comment: How long did it take you to search the whole internet? You just need to read the VSC docs regarding C++ development.